# Spring SAML Extension and Spring Security CSRF Protection Conflict

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

We have a Spring MVC (4.0.5) application with Spring Security (3.2.4) which includes CSRF protection which works fine. We are now adding the SAML security extension (spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.0) which causes an issue with CSRF protection.

The metadata has been configured on SSOCircle and trying to access `http://localhost:8080/myapp` directs to the login page on SSOCircle. After authentication, the browser redirects to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/saml/SSO` and generates an error:

**HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?**

If we turn off CSRF protection, everything works. How can we maintain CSRF protection and still use the SAML extension?

Before setting up the SAML extension, we used a login form and CSRF protection worked and we did not receive an error on the login JSP and it did not have the token.

Code before SAML:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/login.request", "/logout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .hasAnyAuthority("MyRole")
                    .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.request").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login.request?error").permitAll().and().logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.request");
}
```

Code with SAML:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //http.csrf().disable();

    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());

    http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(),
            ChannelProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(samlFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .hasAnyAuthority("MyRole")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

**UPDATE**

After re-enabling CSRF protection and setting logging to DEBUG, here are the logs that occur right after the successful authentication:

```
22.10.2014 16:54:17.374 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.m.support.MultipartFilter -
                Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter

22.10.2014 16:54:17.377 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
                Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.788 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.m.support.MultipartFilter -
                Request [/epass/saml/SSO] is not a multipart request

22.10.2014 16:54:17.790 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
                Checking match of request : '/saml/sso'; against '/resources/**'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.791 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
                /saml/SSO at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MetadataGeneratorFilter'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.793 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
                /saml/SSO at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.795 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
                /saml/SSO at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.797 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository -
                HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

22.10.2014 16:54:17.798 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository -
                No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@b08c9c9. A new one will be created.

22.10.2014 16:54:17.800 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
                /saml/SSO at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'

22.10.2014 16:54:17.801 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter -
                Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@244a79ef

22.10.2014 16:54:17.802 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
                /saml/SSO at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
22.10.2014 16:54:17.805 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter -
                Invalid CSRF token found for `http://localhost:8080/myapp/saml/SSO`

22.10.2014 16:54:17.807 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository -
                SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

22.10.2014 16:54:17.808 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter -
                SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have at least two options.

One is to implement a custom `RequestMatcher` (`org.springframework.security.web.util.RequestMatcher`) which will not match on Spring SAML URLs and provide this to the csrf configuration with:

```
http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(matcher);
```

The other, easier is to define Spring SAML endpoints in a separate http configuration which will not have the csrf protection enabled.

The XML configuration to do this can be similar to:

```
<!-- SAML processing endpoints -->
<security:http pattern="/saml/**" entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:csrf />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

For Java configuration something like this should work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MutlipleHttpConfigurationConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SAMLWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/saml/**");
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
            http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(),
                    ChannelProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(samlFilter(),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class BasicWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
            http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasAnyAuthority("MyRole")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();

            http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Details on defining multiple http configuration with Java configuration can be found in the [Spring Security manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity).

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

`http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/saml/**") ...`

So CSRF is disabled when processing `/saml/**`

from : https://github.com/choonchernlim/spring-security-adfs-saml2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/choonchernlim/security/adfs/saml2/SAMLWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java

Answer (score 5):

For others who might face this issue, I was also able to solve this by forcing the order of the filters.

I replaced this:

```
http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

with this:

```
FilterChainProxy samlFilter = samlFilter();

http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(samlFilter, CsrfFilter.class);
```

and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get pass csrf error by adding <security:csrf disabled="true"/> to the below configuration

```
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST"  ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" />
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter" />
    </security:http>
```